# Ionic 3 : How to display array of arrays?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a following consoled list of array how can i display the list?

[image]

I tried

```
this.item = this.data.["0"]  // this is throwing an error
```

is there any other workaround to achieve this?

Comment: Is the outermost array necessary? Do you have any control of the data structure you're receiving?

Comment: No i dont want the outermost array its completely unnecessary. And the data im receiving is pushed from other page. How can i slice off the the outer array? Because all the data will be coming from other page will be pushed inside the list as u can see in image

Comment: Have you tried this.item = this.data[0] ??

Comment: Yes. It gives me an error this.item is undefined

Comment: Fetch you data by running inner loop.

`<div *ngFor="let a of data" >
 {{a.itemId}}
     <p *ngFor="let b of data.size">{{b.size}}</p>
     <p *ngFor="let c of data.price">{{c.price}}</p>
</div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an array in an array. 
To display the list, you have to loop over the items in the array. Because your output is an array in an array, you can start the loop from the first element of the outer array.

Example:

```
<ion-list>
  <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items[0]">
    {{ item.item_id }}
 </button>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Throws An Error "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Comment: Okay. Can you update your question with the function where you get the data? We might spot something there ...

Comment: @HarshMaisheri Happy to help! On to the next problem ;)

Comment: How can i access this in ts file?
i tried this.items[0].item_id but it says cannot read property of item_id. 
can u help please

Comment: this.items[0] takes you to the first element in the outer array. From there you have three new arrays. To access the item._id of the second inner array, you could use this.items[0][1].item_id. But preferably you should rewrite your data input so you lose the outer (unneccessary) array.

Comment: How can i remove outer array? I couldnt find any solution on this :( Please help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190090/discussion-between-harsh-maisheri-and-tomas-vancoillie).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your parent array is called `data` you can access the first element by using `this.data[0]`. You can also do other things such as loop over the items in the array, etc.

Comment: tired this.data[0] the output comes as undefined :(